# SQL group by without aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm using PostgreSQL, and I have the following table (simplified for the question):

```sql
CREATE TABLE SMSNotification (
    enduser int,
    message int,
    FOREIGN KEY (enduser) REFERENCES EndUser (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (message) REFERENCES Message (id)
);
```

Now, I'd like to batch send the messages. Hence, I'd like to group the notifications by message. The problem is that the GROUP BY operator in SQL aggregates rows. Therefore, I can't get the list of end users in each group:

```sql
SELECT enduser, message from SMSNotification GROUP BY message; /* Doesn't work */
```

I thought of solving this problem by first getting the list of all distinct messages:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT message FROM SMSNotification;
```

Then for each message, getting the list of end users:

```sql
 SELECT enduser FROM SMSNotification WHERE message = current_message;
```

However, this seems inefficient because of the [N+1 selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping). Is there a better solution?

---

**Example:** Consider the following table:

```
+---------+---------+
| enduser | message |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 1       |
| 2       | 1       |
| 3       | 1       |
| 1       | 2       |
| 2       | 2       |
| 1       | 3       |
| 3       | 3       |
+---------+---------+
```

Ideally, I'd like to get a list of tables as an output:

```
+---------+---------+
| enduser | message |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 1       |
| 2       | 1       |
| 3       | 1       |
+---------+---------+

+---------+---------+
| enduser | message |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 2       |
| 2       | 2       |
+---------+---------+

+---------+---------+
| enduser | message |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 3       |
| 3       | 3       |
+---------+---------+
```

However, if I understand correctly, you can't get a list of tables as an output from an SQL query.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input and expected output. I believe you are searching for window functions but I did not understand your use case completely.

Comment: What do you mean with "a list of tables"? A query always returns a result set that can be interpreted as one table. Maybe you want to aggregate the endusers into a list per message? Like @ITChap did in the answer below?

Comment: Yes, ITChap's answer solves my problem. I'd love to learn more about window functions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could aggregate the users into an array like in

```
SELECT array_agg(enduser) AS endusers, message
FROM SMSNotification
GROUP BY message;

 endusers | message 
----------+---------
 {3}      |       3
 {2,3}    |       2
 {1,3}    |       1
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `partition by` command (a window function):

```
select row_number() over (partition by message order by enduser)
    as rn
    , message
    , enduser
from SMSNotification
```

A `group by` reduces the number of rows returned, by aggregating the non-grouped columns, while `partition by` does not affect the number of rows, it just specifies how the output must be displayed or calculated.

Comment: Could you explain what this query does? Perhaps show an example of an output.

Comment: Here is a good article: https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to window functions, but this doesn't help me though. If I was going to loop over the list to get the partitions, then I don't need the row number. I can group by the message. Hence, this is unnecessary work.